# DIV css background Image wont display in IE 8

Tags: html, css, background-image

Our intranet sites are viewed in compatibility mode (ie 8) and css image background not displaying. any tweak to css to accommodate ie 8 issue. (the html, css works in chrome, and ie-9 and onward).

js fiddle is here
jsfiddle.net/729xwamv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVGs are not supported in Internet Explorer 8.

As a solution for this particular scenario, look at [this CSS-Tricks guide](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-svg-fallbacks/) under "Fallback for SVG as CSS background-image". You'll need a PNG version of the image as a fallback.

> The trick here is to find syntax that is supported by (nearly all) browsers that support SVG, but not by the older browsers. Here's the magic:

```
body {
  background: url(fallback.png);
  background: url(background.svg),
    linear-gradient(transparent, transparent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. basically ie-8 does not support svg. i put png and now works.